# How to run a keyboard shortcut via a file?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, running-other-programs

Certain programs for Windows have specific keyboard shortcuts that execute specific functions. I was wondering if there is a way to create a small file that can activate any shortcut by clicking on it?

Example: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> opens up the charms bar in Windows 8. Can I create a file to click on that opens this function for me?

(I want this file to activate a different keyboard shortcut, not the one mentioned above in my example.)

Comment: If my answer is correct please mark it so! Thanks

Comment: @DaniSpringer I marked it as correct. Why do I have a negative?

Comment: Thanks. Because someone down voted your question. Not me.

Comment: Your question seems asked backwards. You say "I want this file to activate a keyboard shortcut". Do you mean "I want this file to BE activated by a keyboard shortcut"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a desktop shortcut.

To do so:

1. Use My Computer or Windows Explorer to locate the object to which
   you want to create a shortcut.
2. Right-click the object, and then
   click Create shortcut.
3. Drag the new shortcut to an open area on the
   desktop.
4. You can also create a keyboard shortcut that will open or do whatever that shortcut would do if you opened it.   See properties.

Reference: <strike>https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/140443</strike> (page no longer available since Windows 10)